# Maximizing variance of color palette

Tags: python, colors, color-palette

I have many color palettes of varying lengths (all at least 3 colors) and am wanting to determine a way where I can extract the 3 most representative colors, or find the colors that would maximize the "variance" of the palette. For example, one palette (in hex) is

```
['#D2691E', '#8B4513', '#A0522D',  '#0000FF', '#668B8B', '#FFC0CB']
```

which is basically three shades of brown, then two shades of blue, then one shade of pink. So I would want my "representative palette" to be one of the shades of brown, one blue, and one pink, perhaps

```
['#D2691E', '#0000FF', '#FFC0CB']
```

or something similar. I realize this may not be completely straightforward, but I'm open to interpretation as to what constitutes representative or variance in color palettes, as long as it's reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: *"K-Means Clustering"* maybe... https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html

Comment: Oh that's perfect! I can just transform hex to rgb, and then make rgb all numeric, and use k means clustering on those 3d points. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we convert the hex representation of each color in palette to it's RGB representation.

```py
from PIL import ImageColor

palette = ['#D2691E', '#8B4513', '#A0522D',  '#0000FF', '#668B8B', '#FFC0CB']
palette_rgb = list(map(lambda x: ImageColor.getcolor(x, "RGB"), palette))
```

Then we want to find the three points that are the furthest apart from each other.
Since the size of your palette is small, we can compute the pairwise distance between all points and then find the 3-cycle with the largest path length through a brute force search.

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from itertools import product

d = squareform(pdist(np.array(palette_rgb)))
best = None
best_dist = 0
for i, j, k in product(range(len(palette)), repeat=3):
    dist = d[i, j] + d[j, k] + d[k, i]
    if dist > best_dist:
        best = (i, j, k)
        best_dist = dist
furthest_colors = [palette[i] for i in best]
```

In this case the colors `['#8B4513', '#0000FF', '#FFC0CB']` are maximally distanced apart.

[Note this solution could be optimized, but for this small application it is likely not worth it to.]